# Selecting Elements that Doesn't Contain a Specified Class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

The Code above determines if `input` has a specified class. However, how could I change the if statement to make it do something when `input` **doesn't** have a specified class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it inside with a `!` negation like this:

```
$("input").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('valid')) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Or just use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) when selecting those elements, like this:

```
$("input:not(.valid)").each(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

This means your original code can also be slimmer (for when it *does* have the class), like this:

```
$("input.valid").each(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("input:not(.valid)").each(function() {
   //Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the negative operator `!`:

```
$("input").each(function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass('valid'))) { // pass this statement if the valid class is not present
        // Do something
    }
});
```